# Sorting two lists

Tags: python, python-2.x, sorting

This sorts two lists (`a`, `b`) according to `a`and returns two sorted lists separately:

```
a = ['apple','carrot','banana']
b = [5,15,10]

s = sorted(zip(a,b))
a,b = map(list, zip(*s))

print a
print b

['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']
[5, 10, 15]
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you understand by *better ways to do this*. Your approach is the usual way of sorting two lists in Python. But there are, of course, multiple methods which may serve different purposes depending on list length for example.

#### Different ways below:

```
>>> list1 = [3,2,4,1,1]
>>> list2 = ['three', 'two', 'four', 'one', 'one2']
>>> list1, list2 = zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
>>> list1
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> list2 
('one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four')
```

The above is not returning a list, but can be easily fixed:

```
>>> list1, list2 = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2))))
>>> list1
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2
['one', 'one2', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

It's worth noting that the above may sacrifice speed for terseness; the in-place version, which takes up 3 lines, is a tad faster on my machine for small lists:

```
>>> %timeit zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.3 us per loop
>>> %timeit tups = zip(list1, list2); tups.sort(); zip(*tups)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.84 us per loop
```

On the other hand, for larger lists, the one-line version could be faster:

```
>>> %timeit zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tups = zip(list1, list2); tups.sort(); zip(*tups)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.51 ms per loop
```

I think the *zip-based* approach is more flexible and is a little more readable, so I prefer it.